# How to define data model for TreeMaps and lists in Javafx

Tags: java, javafx, javabeans

I am making a TreeTableView in javafx. It is a treetable which gets filled dynamically by parsing an XML file. My data basically is in TreeMaps and Lists.At the time it uses no Data model and I have to go through lots of for loops in cell value factory and it makes the program slow, and the code hard to understand. All the examples that I have found are only contain `SimpleStringProperty`. But I have to deal with TreeMaps and Lists. How can i define properties for TreeMaps and lists? Is there any example of using List or treemap properties?
I put some part of the code here to see how it look likes. In the code I have to do lots of comparing with Lists and TreeMaps.

```
private TreeTableView<String> drawTable() {

    root.setExpanded(true);

    long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

    // Set<String> combinedKeys = new HashSet<>(dc.getCombiFunc().keySet());
    Set<String> funcAllKeys = new HashSet<>(dc.getSortedfuncAll().keySet());
    funcAllKeys.removeAll(dc.getCombiFunc().keySet());
    for (List<String> value : dc.getCombiFunc().values()) {
        funcAllKeys.removeAll(value);
    }
    for (String valueremained : funcAllKeys) {
        ArrayList<String> tempNameId = new ArrayList<>();
        tempNameId.add(dc.getSortedfuncAll().get(valueremained));
        root.getChildren().add(new TreeItem<String>(tempNameId.get(0)));
    }


    .
    .
    .
    .
    treeTable.setRoot(root);
    Arrays.stream(dc.getRootKeys()).forEach(
            rootKey -> root.getChildren().add(
                    createTreeItem(dc.getCombiFunc(), rootKey)));

    // ////////////////First column/////////////////////////
    /**
     * creates first column with no caption and sets treeview for that.
     * */
    TreeTableColumn<String, String> firstColumn = new TreeTableColumn<>("");
    treeTable.getColumns().add(firstColumn);// Tree column

    firstColumn
            .setCellValueFactory(new Callback<CellDataFeatures<String, String>, ObservableValue<String>>() {
                public ObservableValue<String> call(
                        CellDataFeatures<String, String> p) {
                    return new ReadOnlyStringWrapper(p.getValue()
                            .getValue());
                }
            });

    // //////////////////Rest Columns////////////////////////
    /**
     * go through all organizations which have a function and make column
     */
    int counter=0;
    for (Entry<String, String> ent : dc.getSortedAssignedOrg().entrySet()) {

        TreeTableColumn<String, ArrayList<String>> col = new TreeTableColumn<>();
        Label label = new Label(ent.getValue());
        ..
        .
        .
        .
        .
        col.setPrefWidth(45);
        // cell Value Factory////////////////////////
        col.setCellValueFactory(new Callback<TreeTableColumn.CellDataFeatures<String, ArrayList<String>>, ObservableValue<ArrayList<String>>>() {

            @Override
            public ObservableValue<ArrayList<String>> call(
                    CellDataFeatures<String, ArrayList<String>> param) {
                TreeMap<String, List<String>> temp = (TreeMap<String, List<String>>) dc
                        .getFuncTypeOrg().clone();

                ArrayList<String> result = new ArrayList<>();

                for (int i = 0; i < dc.getFuncTypeOrg().size(); i++) {

                    List<String> list = temp.firstEntry().getValue();

                    String key = temp.firstEntry().getKey();

                    // sets parent for each parent cell
                    if (dc.getRooKeyByName().contains(
                            param.getValue().getValue())) {
                        if (list.get(5).equals(label.getText())) {
                            for (Entry<String, Set<String>> entry : dc
                                    .getResultnoduplicatName().entrySet()) {
                                if (entry.getKey().contains(
                                        param.getValue().getValue())
                                        && entry.getValue().contains(
                                                (list.get(1)))
                                        && list.get(5).equals(
                                                label.getText())) {

                                    result.add("parent");

                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }// end parent

                    // name is equal to column

                    if (list.get(1).equals(param.getValue().getValue())
                            && list.get(5).equals(label.getText())) {
                .
                .
                .
                .
                .
                .

                    } else if (!dc.getRooKeyByName().contains(
                            param.getValue().getValue())
                            && (list.get(1).equals(
                                    param.getValue().getValue())
                                    && !list.get(5).equals(label.getText()) || (!list
                                    .get(1).equals(
                                            param.getValue().getValue())))) {
                        result.add("white");

                    }
                    temp.remove(key);

                }// end for

                return new ReadOnlyObjectWrapper<ArrayList<String>>(result);
            }
        }); // end cell Value Factory

        System.out.println("Im here 2...");

         long endTime2   = System.currentTimeMillis();
         long totalTime2 = endTime2 - startTime2;
         System.out.println(totalTime2);

        // //////////////cellfactory/////////////////////////
        col.setCellFactory(new Callback<TreeTableColumn<String, ArrayList<String>>, TreeTableCell<String, ArrayList<String>>>() {
            @Override
            public TreeTableCell<String, ArrayList<String>> call(
                    TreeTableColumn<String, ArrayList<String>> param) {
                return new TreeTableCell<String, ArrayList<String>>() {
                    private List<Double> result = new ArrayList<Double>();
                    private List<Double> weight = new ArrayList<>();
                    private double lastresult = new Double(0);

                    public void updateItem(ArrayList<String> item,
                            boolean empty) {

                        super.updateItem(item, empty);

                        if (item == null || empty) { // extra items under
                                                        // last row
                            setStyle(null);
                            setText(null);
                        } else if (item != null) {

                            if (item.contains("N.A.")) {
                                this.setStyle("-fx-background-color:gray");
                                // setTooltip(new Tooltip(item.get(2)));
                                float weightInt = Float.parseFloat(item
                                        .get(0));
                                setText("N.A." + "\n" + weightInt);
                            } 
                            ......
                            ......//more else if here
                            .....

                             else if (item.contains("white")) {
                                this.setStyle("-fx-background-color:linear-gradient(from 41px 34px to 50px 50px, reflect, #ff7f50 30%, #faebd7  47%); ");
                                setText("");
                            } else if (item.contains("parent")) {

                                for (Map.Entry<String, Set<String>> entryResult : dc
                                        .getResultnoduplicatName()
                                        .entrySet()) {
                            .
                            .
                            .
                            .
                            .
                            .
                            .
                            .
                            .

                                                    } else
                                                        result.add((double) 0);
                                                }
                                            }

                                        }
                                        lastresult = ((result
                                                .stream()
                                                .mapToDouble(
                                                        Double::doubleValue)
                                                .sum()) / (weight
                                                .stream()
                                                .mapToDouble(
                                                        Double::doubleValue)
                                                .sum()));
                                        // entryResult.getValue().size());
                                        setText(lastresult + "");
                                    }

                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                };
            };

        });// end cell factory

        treeTable.getColumns().add(col);
```